# What is the State of the art method for full body gesture recognition in images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am working on gesture recognition in images and the best way that I am aware of, is whether using end to end approaches with deep neural networks or extracting body joint positions in an image and then doing some pre-processing on these joints positions and finally, feeding them to a classifier. I wanted to now what is the state of the art method for full body gesture recognition in images and if there are some good papers or a blog post reviewing different methods, as I have problem finding one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planing to train a model which is using images taken by a single camera, I encourage you to take a look at [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~thrun/papers/waldherr.gestures-journal.pdf) paper. They use a camera to track a person and recognize gestures involving arm motion. In this paper, two alternative methods for gesture recognition are compared: a **template based** approach and a **neural network** approach.

However, another way which I suggest is using depth cameras such as [Intel Realsense](https://www.intelrealsense.com/) or [Microsoft Kinect](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect) cameras. [This](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bunthit_Watanapa/publication/271497327_Human_gesture_recognition_using_Kinect_camera/links/5710af3d08ae68dc790988e0.pdf) paper uses depth cameras for full body gesture recognition. I think using these cameras take your project a step ahead and more accurate in initial states.